# TypeScript import

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, import

I have the next import statement in my .ts file:

```
import { IRemoteAudioSource } from "js/Abstractions/Interfaces/AudioSource/IRemoteAudioSource";
```

Visual studio finds such file, no problems. But when i run my solution i get the error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "js/Abstractions/AbstractClasses/AudioModel". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

And when I try to specify the relative path(`import { IRemoteAudioSource } from "/js/Abstractions/Interfaces/AudioSource/IRemoteAudioSource";`), visual studio does not find such a file.

What am i doing wrong?

**tsconfig.json:**

`{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "module": "ES6",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "watch": false,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true
    },
    "plugins": [ { "name": "tslint-language-service" } ]
}`

Comment: The answer is in the error, `import { IRemoteAudioSource } from "./js/Abstractions/Interfaces/AudioSource/IRemoteAudioSource"`;

Answer (score 0):

You have to import starting with "/".
Always do a import with folders way.

Like you have to do as -

import { IRemoteAudioSource } from "./js/Abstractions/Interfaces/AudioSource/IRemoteAudioSource";

as error says.

Answer (score 0):

I added this to compiler option

```
"paths": {
    "/*": [ "./*" ]
},
```

and used relative path for import. These actions solved the problem